# Sens de "palsambouille"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J'ai trouvé le mot *palsambouille* dans les derniers pages de *Normance* (1954) de L.-F. Céline :

> la bignolle non plus !... **palsambouille** ! je vous l'oubliais !... elle
> est toujours avec nous !...

Je croyais que c'était un néologisme, mais j'ai trouvé sur Google environ 10 résultats avec ce mot. À titre d'exemple :

> Palsambouille ! J'ai oublié les framboises... ([Source](https://www.lemondededuralas.org/t134p125-bosquet-de-cerisiers))

D'après les exemples, je suppose qu'il s'agit d'une interjection synonyme de *[parbleu](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parbleu)*. Est-ce correct ? S'agit-il d'une interjection employée plutôt dans la langue parlée ?

Comment: Le deuxième lien est bourré de porno. Pas très agréable. En tout cas, ces "auteurs" ont peut-être lu Céline.....

Comment: @Lambie Désolé, je ne l'avais pas remarqué. Merci de m'avoir prévenu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'après le *Petit traité de l'injure*<sup>1</sup> c'est la déformation de [palsambleu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/palsambleu).

> [Le sacré] étant sacré, on évite souvent de livrer le [nom de Dieu] brut de fonderie et de décoffrage. Consensus aidant, des jurons de type « nom de Dieu », « sacredieu » ou « par le sang de dieu  » se retrouvèrent soudain repeints en « nom de Zeus », « sacrebleu » et « palsambleu », voire en « palsambouille » chez Céline lui-même.

Et je ne pense pas que ce soit très employé, je ne l'avais jamais entendu. Je pense que c'est beaucoup moins connu que sacrebleu ou palsambleu qui sont pourtant passé de mode depuis longtemps.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Pierre Merle, éditions l'Archipel, 2014.</sup>